# How can I cache function results and update cache value everytime invoke the function?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, caching

I am here looking for some help:

I have a function, written by `Python2.7`, it took a long time to return results, so I would like using `cache` to store result, everytime the function was invoked, value in cache should returned and a new result return from function should update the cache value asynchromously. Is this possible?

for short:

1. cache function result.
2. everytime invoke the function, return cache value if function cache_key in cache, otherwise, return a default value. In the meantime, get the real-time function return value, and update the cache.

I've tried:

**1. cachetools**

```
import time
from cachetools import cached, TTLCache
cache = TTLCache(maxsize=1, ttl=360)

@cached(cache)
def expensive_io():
    time.sleep(300)
    return 1.0
```

But first time the `expensive_io` function was invoked, I still have to wait for 300s, and can't update the cache value until ttl timeout. After ttl timeout, I have to spend another 300s to wait for the results.

So, I wonder maybe I can use threading?:

**2. threading**

```
from threading import Thread
import Queue

class asynchronous(object):
    def __init__(self, func, maxsize=128, cache=OrderedDict()):
        self.func = func
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.cache = cache
        self.currsize = len(cache)

        def getfuncthread(*args, **kwargs):
            key = self.cache_key("{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self.func.__name__, str(*args), str(**kwargs)))
            if self.currsize >= self.maxsize:
                self.cache.popitem(False)
            if not self.cache:
                self.cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
                self.queue.put(self.cache[key])

        def returnthread(*args, **kwargs):
            key = self.cache_key("{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self.func.__name__, str(*args), str(**kwargs)))
            if key in self.cache:
                return self.cache[key]
            else:
                return 2222

        self.returnthread = returnthread
        self.getfuncthread = getfuncthread

    def cache_key(self, s):
        return hashlib.sha224(s).hexdigest()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queue = Queue()
        thread1 = Thread(target=self.getfuncthread, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread2 = Thread(target=self.returnthread, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread1.start()
        thread2.start()
        return asynchronous.Result(self.queue, thread2)

    class NotYetDoneException(Exception):
        def __init__(self, message):
            self.message = message

    class Result(object):
        def __init__(self, queue, thread):
            self.queue = queue
            self.thread = thread

        def is_done(self):
            return not self.thread.is_alive()

        def get_result(self):
            if not self.is_done():
                raise asynchronous.NotYetDoneException('the call has not yet completed its task')

            if not hasattr(self, 'result'):
                self.result = self.queue.get()
            return self.result

@asynchronous
def expensive_io(n):
    time.sleep(300)
    return n*n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # sample usage
    import time

    result1 = expensive_io.start(2)
    result2 = expensive_io.start(2)
    result3 = expensive_io.start(4)
    try:
        print "result1 {0}".format(result1.get_result())
        print "result2 {0}".format(result2.get_result())
        print "result3 {0}".format(result3.get_result())
    except asynchronous.NotYetDoneException as ex:
        print ex.message
```

I was thinking, two threads in the asynchronous decorator:

`returnThread` is used to return value from cache if cache_key in cache, if not, return a default value immediately.

`getfuncthread` is used to get function value by invoking func, and put it in cache and queue.

That seems logical, but still not working.

**3. asyncio**

Can I use `asyncio` ?  But python2.7 not support `asyncio`, I found `trollius` package. But still dont know how to deal with it.

Any ideas would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are forced to use Python 2.7, you won't have access to many options from the PSF's modern library implementations, including those with asyncio (as you said) and what you want (functools). Here's a solution that uses a function created by a close friend of mine (https://github.com/iwalton3), and some boilerplate code from the CPython github source:

```
def wraps(wrapped,
          assigned = WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
          updated = WRAPPER_UPDATES):
    """Decorator factory to apply update_wrapper() to a wrapper function

       Returns a decorator that invokes update_wrapper() with the decorated
       function as the wrapper argument and the arguments to wraps() as the
       remaining arguments. Default arguments are as for update_wrapper().
       This is a convenience function to simplify applying partial() to
       update_wrapper().
    """
    return partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped,
                   assigned=assigned, updated=updated)
class partial:
    """New function with partial application of the given arguments
    and keywords.
    """

    __slots__ = "func", "args", "keywords", "__dict__", "__weakref__"

    def __new__(cls, func, /, *args, **keywords):
        if not callable(func):
            raise TypeError("the first argument must be callable")

        if hasattr(func, "func"):
            args = func.args + args
            keywords = {**func.keywords, **keywords}
            func = func.func

        self = super(partial, cls).__new__(cls)

        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.keywords = keywords
        return self

    def __call__(self, /, *args, **keywords):
        keywords = {**self.keywords, **keywords}
        return self.func(*self.args, *args, **keywords)

    def __reduce__(self):
        return type(self), (self.func,), (self.func, self.args,
               self.keywords or None, self.__dict__ or None)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        if not isinstance(state, tuple):
            raise TypeError("argument to __setstate__ must be a tuple")
        if len(state) != 4:
            raise TypeError(f"expected 4 items in state, got {len(state)}")
        func, args, kwds, namespace = state
        if (not callable(func) or not isinstance(args, tuple) or
           (kwds is not None and not isinstance(kwds, dict)) or
           (namespace is not None and not isinstance(namespace, dict))):
            raise TypeError("invalid partial state")

        args = tuple(args) # just in case it's a subclass
        if kwds is None:
            kwds = {}
        elif type(kwds) is not dict: # XXX does it need to be *exactly* dict?
            kwds = dict(kwds)
        if namespace is None:
            namespace = {}

        self.__dict__ = namespace
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.keywords = kwds

def make_dynamic(function):
    cache = {}
    @wraps(function)
    def result(*args, clear_cache=False, ignore_cache=False, skip_cache=False, **kwargs):
        nonlocal cache
        call = (args, tuple(kwargs.items()))
        if clear_cache:
            cache = {}
        if call in cache and not ignore_cache:
            return cache[call]
        res = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if not skip_cache:
            cache[call] = res
        return res
    return result
```

Altogether, this means you should be able to decorate your expensive IO calculations with a `@make_dynamic` tag above your `def functionName(args, ...):` line. However, take care to ensure that all `args` are hashable. For any readers who are not familiar with *hashability*, it just means that you can use the `hash(object_name)` on the interpreter and it returns a unique integer. These types include strings, numbers, tuples, etc.